# Is this prompt a problem please excuse my ignorance

Tags: updates, google-chrome, 16.04

> ```
> W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)  
>
> W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:A040830F7FAC5991
> ```

I have an asus laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 having problems in chrome-stable

uninstalled purged
I still get this message in terminal when updating Firefox looks like it is a problem, ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem to you.  It is only a warning, and that is something that Google has to fix by upgrading their keys.

More information can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Apt/Sha1Removal).

There has also been a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596074#) filed.  Feel free to star it to help push the bug along.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem that interferes with anything; you can ignore that message.

See the following AskUbuntu questions about it for more information:

[Key uses weak digest algorithm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764927/key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm)

[How to fix apt: Signature by key uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1) after installing Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1-after-install)